Pint doesn't recognize my custom defined units
I'm using Pint to handle units for some files that I'm analyzing.
The files contain 10,000ish lines of data for 10 - 100 different variables each. The units of the variables are given in the files, and some units are not contained in the default units of Pint, e.g. 'Ohmm'.
I added these units to a text file, my_def.txt, as:
ohmm = [resistivity] = ohm * meter = Ωm
@alias ohmm = Ohmm

To avoid avoid creating multiple instances of the Pint unit registry, I followed the docs and instantiated Pint in my __init__.py file, where I also loaded my definitions, e.g.
from pint import UnitRegistry
ureg = UnitRegistry()
Q_ = ureg.Quantity
ureg.load_definitions('<PATH>\\my_def.txt')

It all works in a naive unit test, where the following code snippet works fine:
from .. import ureg, Q_   # .. is the directory where my __init__.py file is found
r3 = Q_(3000., 'Ohmm')
dist = 10 * ureg.meter
r4 = r3 / dist

But when I try this in my project:
from .. import ureg, Q_   # .. is the directory where my __init__.py file is found
import pint_xarray
import xarray as xr
data, units = read_data_with_units_from_file()
x = xr.DataArray(name='name', data=data)
x = x.pint.quantify({'name': units}) 

I get the following error when the units in the file is 'Ohmm':
ValueError: Cannot parse units:
    invalid units for variable 'rdep': Ohmm (parameter) (reason: 'Ohmm' is not defined in the unit registry)

What could the reason be that it doesn't work in the Python project, but works in my unit test?
